# iPhone Simulator - How to toggle internet connection?

Tags: ios-simulator

Looking to toggle network connectivity in the iPhone simulator. This is on a mac mini with wired ethernet.

One suggestion was to turn the AirPort on/off but that had no effect in the simulator.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the ethernet cable out. You may also be able to achieve what you want by disabling the port in System Preferences > Networking.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that since it would throw a big wrench into getting development work done. Last resort, I guess.

Comment: Why is this a minus one vote? This solution works perfectly, albeit being annoying.